# MATLAB throw YDATA size error when using lsqcurvefit X and Y are of the same size

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to make a simple function that will do some curve fitting for me. I use this for the fitting

```
data = importdata('in.dat');
X = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,2);
err = data(:,3);
disp(size(X))
disp(size(Y))
F = @(x,xdata)x(1)+x(2);
x0 = [8,2];
stuff=lsqcurvefit(F,x0,X,Y);


fout = fopen('out.dat','w');
fprintf('kappa = ',x(1));
fprintf('alpha = ',y(2));
fclose(fout);
exit
```

But I get an error

> lsqcurvefit(F,x0,X,Y)
>   Error using lsqcurvefit (line 248)
>   Function value and YDATA sizes are not equal.

This error reads to me as if `X` and `Y` are not of the same size. However, on this sample data

```
X =

         0
    0.6931
    1.3863
Y =
   -5.2546
   -6.6642
   -8.0545
```

Just to make sure, I checked the sizes.

```
>> size(X)
size(X)

ans =

     3     1

>> size(Y)
size(Y)

ans =

     3     1
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `F` returns a scalar where a vector of the size of `Y` (or `xdata` as it is called the scope of `F`) is expected.

A working example would be, for instance:

```
F = @(x,xdata) x(1) * xdata;
```